# How to write comparisons with undefined variables in PHP

Tags: php, undeclared-identifier

I'm learning that I've gotten into a bad programming habit of not always defining variables or properties before using them in a comparison operator. I'd never noticed this before, but now that I'm developing in a different environment I'm getting the notices.

For example:

```
if ($test_var)
    echo "Do some stuff";
```

This is easy enough to solve with `isset` or `empty` depending on the need.

However, I also tend to use these undeclared variables/properties in comparisons like so:

```
if (($test_int == 1) && ($test_str == "hello world"))
    echo "Do some stuff";
```

This is a lot harder to rewrite with `isset` or `empty` statements. I could wrap the whole thing in a bunch of `issets`, but then you very quickly get nested spaghetti code that impacts readability and maintainability.

I understand WHY this is happening, but am looking for help finding the best solution as a general practice.

Apologies if this solution has been posted before. I looked, but all I could find were questions about why notices were appearing, not specifically how to write comparisons.

Comment: This is why I ignore undefined variable messages...

Comment: ` I also tend to use these undeclared variables/properties in comparisons ` How can you compare something that does not yet exist ? Thats like saying is `apple equal to `....computers can't just guess they need two values to compare them. Doesn't make sense thats not logical and code is logic driven :P You could declare the variable before hand so you don't need to worry about using `isset`.

Comment: @Kolink That's terrible advice imho

Comment: @MikeB i agree! Ignoring the messages is just refusing to code properly.

Comment: @MikeB I wasn't giving advice. Nothing about my statement was a suggestion nor in any way encouraging this.

Comment: You should declare all the variables you are going to use at the beginning of the script

Comment: @Kolnik: Do you ignore the oil light on your car's dashboard too?

Comment: true, but in practice I always thought that the undeclared variable evaluated to `false` or `null`.

Comment: Think like this.. if i said "does needle exist in haystack" you have to searching everything - same if the script has to check every where in memory to find the variable. unless you declare it won't know where to look for it.

Comment: I never thought of it that way. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: No problem - to summaries what you're doing is not going to help if you learn other languages. I think the answer is clear now :P Best tick who ever has  the best answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to go would be to initialise these variables you do comparisons on, by assigning some sort of value like `null` before your procedure.

```
$chicken = null;

// some code that generates $egg value

if ($egg) {
    $chicken = "Leghorn";
}


if ("Leghorn" === $chicken) {
    echo "I say ..I say...boy...";
}
```

So if `$chicken = null;` was missing in the example above, and the value of `$egg` was false, you would normally get a PHP notice.

Comment: It seems like this is the consensus, and there is no easier/cleaner way to write comparisons. Funny, when I started coding I always declared variables at the top of every program. Not sure where I picked up this bad habit of not declaring vars. Probably snuck in because you can usually get away with it in PHP.

Comment: @DavidGrenier true, something like this is often mandatory in many other languages, so I find it good practice to look at how other languages do things

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the notices, check your error reporting settings:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

(If you have a script that runs at the top of every page, you can do something like:
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

Otherwise, you could declare your variables near the top (probably a better idea).

Unrelated: It's a personal thing, but if you enclose your IF statements in braces, it'll be easier to decipher later!

Comment: Ignoring notices instead of correcting your script is not really good advice.

Comment: Curtis - agreed on the braces. I normally use them but stripped them out here for easy readability.

Comment: "Otherwise, you could declare your variables near the top (probably a better idea)."